# Совет по реализации расписания

Tags: java, android

хотел бы спросить как лучше сделать.

Имеется учебное расписание, из которого я хочу сделать Android - приложение. Я собираюсь на одном RecyclerView размещать расписание на один день.

В учебном расписании имеются пропуски, когда пар нет.

Вопрос касается того, что делать с этими пропусками?

1. Не добавлять их в базу данных на сервере, (при парсинге) а при запросе из android и при переносе элементов в adapter как то проверять, есть ли элемент с таким временем (соответствие времени парам-занятиям), если нету, то добавлять самому пропуск. Но что тогда с полями класса в ViewHolder делать(они же будут все будут Null, кроме времени)(или можно другой ViewHolder с одним полем сделать, на подобии "сейчас отдых", его можно в тот же adapter засунуть?). Также получается, что при изменении времени организации, придется обновлять приложение, так как при добавлении пустых элементов, у него будет другие временные промежутки.
2. При добавлении на сервер (добавлять и пустые элементы, все будет по Null, кроме времени и даты), но тогда увеличивается база данных, что увеличивает встроенную базу данных (например Room), и трафик (так как Json будет больше по размерам)

Выслушаю любые идеи, вплоть до выбора других элементов для отображении в Android

Comment: Если речь идет о реализации списка через Architecture Components, хотел уточнить а обязательно нужны поля с переменами ?

Comment: @GinTasan а что у вас модель данных будет без полей чтоль? Ведь мы список моделей заносим в адаптер

Comment: Нет) вы меня не так поняли, я имел ввиду , поля с пропусками, поля, когда пар нет

Comment: Ну я хотел бы чтобы пропуски тоже отображались. Чтобы можно было отобразить какой временной интервал сейчас идет. Например будет 1 и 4 пара. В списке будут 2 элемента, 1 пара прошла и не отображается что сейчас идет

Comment: Если интервал задавать в ручную, то нет необходимости хранить промежуточные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать перехватить результат из БД в классе, в котором она реализована и переписать возвращаемый в метод loadInitial List (Или смотря как вы там реализовали) или в  методе loadInitial изменить уже полученные данные из класса с БД, но эти варианты довольно таки муторные, можно добавить данные о полном расписании (Пропуски пар , сами пары и т.д.) - будет намного проще, однако данных не так уж и много. Можно попробовать так же как и в первых вариантах - перехватить список, но только добавить в таблицу NULL значения, и изменить их перед передачей в callback.onResult(result, 0);.